# How do Bitwise Trie lookups work

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, full-text-search, bit-manipulation, trie

I have been looking into data structures recently, and keep coming across "Bitwise Trie"'s

I know how a trie works, but I don't get the following:

1. Data Structure of a Bitwise tree Node.

For comparison, a poor man's implementation of a simple fixed length array Trie looks something like the following:

```
public class Node
{
    Node[] _nodes  = new Node[27]; // 26 = A-Z + NULL

    public Node Next(char c)
    {
        if (c == '$')
            return _nodes[26];

        return _nodes[c - 'A'];
    }
}
```

What would something similar look like in a 'Bitwise Tree'?

**EDIT**

Following @samsag comment, it is counting leading zeroes, not number of bits set!

1. How counting number of "`1`" bits helps.

e.g. Lets say for instance

```
EOL   = 000 (0 bits set)    
A     = 001 (1 bit set)
B     = 010 (1 bit set)
C     = 011 (2 bits set)
D     = 100 (1 bit set)
E     = 101 (2 bits set)
F     = 111 (3 bits set)
```

How does bit counting help when there are so many clashes?
What kind of algorithm/hash/bitwise operations do I need to perform to be able to take advantage of bit counting?

Comment: Are you sure the algorithm involves counting set bits and not leading zeros? Can you link to an example?

Comment: @samsag you are right, it is counting leading (first bit set, not number of bits set)! Can't believe I've been chasing my tail because I interpreted something wrong! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie mentioned that you get the first bit set using clz! Not sure why I interpreted it this way! Makes more sense now